# node js request multiple urls same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to request multiple urls with npm s request library and return results in on json

my code is that but not working.

```
request({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId="+item+"&key=AIzaSyCPv-dasd&maxResults=100&",
   url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId="+item+"&key=AIzaSyCPv-dasd&maxResults=100&",
    json: true
},
```

Comment: and what should it return ?

Comment: doesn't matter its not working

Comment: and what should it return ? :3 (it does matter :) )

Comment: json response from youtube.... it does matter? json response, because as this request url : url : style not working

Comment: for example if first url returns json `{prop1 : "hello",prop2 : 2}` and second url returns `{prop1: "hello",prop2 : 1, prop3: [2,3]}` do you want `{prop1 : "hellohello",prop2: 3,prop3 : [2,3]}` or `{prop1: "hello",prop2: 2,prop3: [2,3]}` or ...

Comment: or do you want array of responses ?

Comment: thanks I find it with asynx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like promisify of bluebird, in order to use promises:

```
const bluebird = require('bluebird');
const promiseRequest = bluebird.promisify(require('request'));

Promise.all([
  promiseRequest(//request1 here),
  promiseRequest(//request2 here),
])
.then(function(res1, res2) {
  //Deal with results here
})
.catch(function(error) {
  //Deal with error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the request library you mentioned is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), then it allows only one URL per request, so you'll need to make a separate call for each URL you need.

Hope it helps.